# Scanning both doubles and characters

Tags: c

My program has several inputs all of which are doubles. The user should enter all except one of his/her choice. the one unentered should be a question mark. How do I find the question mark?

Comment: Have you tried something that isn't working? If so show the code and we can help you understand what's not working.

Comment: `while (scanf("%lf", &dbl)) { ... }    //when you arrive here, you have your question mark, you can now do whatever and continue scanfing doubles`

Comment: @szczurcio `while (scanf("%lf", &dbl) == 1)` because it can return `-1` or `EOF` and that would evaluate as true.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :while (scanf("%lf", &variable_name) == 1), if it returned anything but 0, then change the int main(void) to void (main).(it does not work on all IDE and compilers).